# VBA - How to make the code work when the Column number is dynamic?

Tags: vba, dynamic

How to make the code work when the Column number is dynamic?

I want the code to work when some of the time i need to work with col B and some of the times is col C (the title stay the same)?

thanks.

Comment: "the code"?? Show us the code!

Comment: Maybe use variables?

Answer (score 0):

Use variables .. I use the following function to get my columns:

```
'-----------------------------------------------------------------
' Purpose           Retrieves the column number - searches in a
'                   listobject header
' Requires          string to search
'                   range (listobject name)
' Important         needs range with [#headers],  eg
'                   Range("Customers[#Headers]")
' Example           To find out in which column number 'Phone' in
'                   table 'Customers' is located, you use
'                   GetColumn("Phone",Range("Customers[#Headers]")
'-----------------------------------------------------------------
Function GetColumn(str As String, rng As Range) As Integer
GetColumn = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(str, rng, 0)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, how can i used it with Sub() ?

```
 Public Function GetColumn(str As String, rng As Range) As Integer
 GetColumn = Application.Sheets("Sheet1").Match("Supplier", "POC[#Headers]", 0)

End Function
 Sub i()






 NumRows = cells(Rows.Count, "e").End(xlUp).Row
   For i = 2 To NumRows

   Supplier = cells(i, 16).Value

    Select Case Supplier
        Case "EDLC", "ANC", "EdTD", "ENC", "APASA P", "EBANROPE", "EVANC"

         GetColumn.Value = "Zaya"


     End Select

  Next i

  End Sub
```